# 10x10 bitmapped square with bits

Tags: c++, matrix, bitwise

This program prints out a 10x10 square and uses only bit operations. It works well, but I don't like that global array.

Can you tell me if the code is proper or not?

```
#include <iostream>

const std::size_t HEIGHT = 10;
const std::size_t WIDTH = 10;

char graphics[WIDTH/8][HEIGHT];

inline void set_bit(std::size_t x, std::size_t y)
{
    graphics[(x) / 8][y] |= (0x80 >> ((x) % 8));
}

void print_screen(void)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < HEIGHT; y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < WIDTH/8+1; x++)
        {
            for (int i = 0x80; i != 0; i = (i >> 1))
            {
                if ((graphics[x][y] & i) != 0)
                    std::cout << "*";
                else
                    std::cout << " ";
            }
        }
            std::cout<<std::endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    for(int x = 0; x < WIDTH; x++)
    {
        for(int y = 0; y < HEIGHT; y++)
        {
            if(x == 0 || y == 0 || x == WIDTH-1 || y == HEIGHT-1)
                set_bit(x,y);
        }
    }
    print_screen();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why not pass the array as an argument and then make it local to `main`?

Comment: because in the set_bit I have to change it. I tried using as a reference, but it said I couldn't.

Comment: I'd use a 2D `std::array` as it's easier to handle, adding on to what busy_wait is suggesting.

Comment: it's a solution for an exercise (from a c++ book). I had to use bits :)

Comment: `std::vector<bool>` is optimized for space and since this is C++ you should prefer to use `vector` over an array anyway.

Comment: @busy_wait: In that case (with bits), you're right.  If bits weren't involved here, then in general, `std::array` would be good if dealing with a fixed size.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That global array is indeed not good.  You'll need to pass around an array, but you shouldn't do it with a C-style array.  Doing that will cause it to *decay to a pointer*, which you should avoid in C++.  If you have C++11, you could use [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array), which will be set at an initial size.  But if you don't have C++11, and also want to adjust the size, use an [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).  You can also compare the two [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4424579/stdvector-versus-stdarray-in-c).  Either way, you'll be able to pass any of them around nicely, and it's something you should be doing in C++ anyway.

**To match your environment, the following code does *not* utilize C++11.**

I'll use `std::vector` here, but this can be done with other STL storage containers.  Here's what a 2D vector would look like:

```
std::vector<std::vector<T> > matrix; // where T is the type
```

This type does look long, and you may not want to type it out each time.  To "shorten" it, you can use `typedef` to create an alias (which is *not* a new type):

```
typedef std::vector<std::vector<T> > Matrix;
```

With that, you can use this type as such:

```
Matrix matrix;
```

and create the 2D vector of a specific size.

*However*, this is where the syntax gets nasty (especially lengthy).  It's not set to a specific size, so you can just push vectors into it to increase the size.  For a fixed size (using your size and data type), you'll have something like this:

```
std::vector<std::vector<char> > matrix(HEIGHT, std::vector<char>(WIDTH));
```

This can be made shorter by having *another* `typedef` to serve as a dimension of the matrix.  This will also make it a little clearer what the vector means in this context.

```
typedef std::vector<char> MatrixDim;
```

It is then applied to the `Matrix` `typedef`:

```
typedef std::vector<MatrixDim> Matrix;
```

The 2D initialization will then become this:

```
Matrix matrix(HEIGHT, MatrixDim(WIDTH));
```

Now you can finally use this in `main()` and pass it to the other functions.  Before you do that, you'll need a different loop counter type.  With an STL storage container, you should use [`std::size_type`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/226302/where-can-i-look-up-the-definition-of-size-type-for-vectors-in-the-c-stl).  With `std::vector<char>`, specifically, you'll have:

```
std::vector<char>::size_type;
```

You can use yet another `typedef` for this:

```
typedef MatrixDim::size_type MatrixDimSize;
```

---

Here's what the functions will look like with the changes (explanations provided).  I've also included some additional changes, which are also explained.  The entire program with [my changes](http://ideone.com/rquKtG) applied and produces the same output as [yours](http://ideone.com/mEaziU).

**`setbit()`:**

```
inline void set_bit(Matrix& matrix, MatrixDimSize x, MatrixDimSize y)
{
    matrix[(x) / 8][y] |= (0x80 >> ((x) % 8));
}
```

- An additional parameter of type `Matrix` is added.  The matrix is passed in by reference and modified within the function.
- The `std::size_t` parameters were replaced with the `MatrixDimSize` type.

**`print_screen()`:**

```
void print_screen(Matrix const& matrix)
{
    for (MatrixDimSize y = 0; y < HEIGHT; y++)
    {
        for (MatrixDimSize x = 0; x < WIDTH/8+1; x++)
        {
            for (int i = 0x80; i != 0; i >>= 1)
            {
                std::cout << (((matrix[x][y] & i) != 0) ? '*' : ' ');
            }
        }

        std::cout << "\n";
    }
}
```

- A parameter of type `Matrix` is added.  The matrix is passed in by `const&`, which is necessary as the function displays the matrix but does not modify it.  It's also cheaper to pass it this way as opposed to copying (passing by value).
- `MatrixDimSize` is added for the loop counter types.
- The `if`/`else` is replaced with an equivalent ternary statement.
- A newline is done with `"\n"` as opposed to `std::endl`.  The latter also flushes the buffer, which is slower.  You just need the former.
- `i = (i >> 1)` is shortened to `i >>= 1`.

**`Main()`:**

```
int main()
{
    Matrix matrix(HEIGHT, MatrixDim(WIDTH));

    for (MatrixDimSize x = 0; x < WIDTH; x++)
    {
        for (MatrixDimSize y = 0; y < HEIGHT; y++)
        {
            if (x == 0 || y == 0 || x == WIDTH-1 || y == HEIGHT-1)
            {
                set_bit(matrix, x, y);
            }
        }
    }

    print_screen(matrix);
}
```

- Both matrix vector `typedef`s are applied.
- `MatrixDimSize` is added for the loop counter types.
- The matrix is passed to and modified *only* by `set_bit()`.

  - It is passed to `print_screen()` and is *not* modified.